# How to achieve table like format in Crystal Report

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

How to fill tables occupying the whole page in crystal Report provided with data.

Currently this is what I achieve so far, but I want also to fill with table row the whole page even without data.

[image]

**Please refer the should be output.**

[image]

Comment: Try using a cross-tab.  Othen than that the only thing I can think of is manual lines.  CR is not that friendly when it comes to this.

Comment: Yeah, That what I'm thinking